# How to make a field in database in django that only takes few predefined inputs from drop down list

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django and i had no idea how to shorten my question.
My problem is i am making a model in django. I have made a class user. In that class i have a character type name, integer type id, and a integer type age.
I want a field in which user can only select from a few predefined inputs, like section A, B or C. Because then I can easily use form class to render a form to a HTML page without any coding. I know I can use a charfield to save A, B or C but is there a way to do what I want ?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use [Field.choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices) attribute on your model class. Please visit the link for more in-depth explanation & examples.

> **Field.choices**
>
> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for this field. If this is given, the default form widget will be a select box with these choices instead of the standard text field.

So you could use it like this in your model class:

```
class myClass(models.Model):
    AVAILABLE_CHOICES = (
        ('a', 'Section A'),
        ('b', 'Section B'),
        ('c', 'Section C'),
    )
    
    section = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=AVAILABLE_CHOICES, default='a')
    ...
```

> The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name.